# Why is 'route.params.id' unavailable/undefined in setup method?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm working with vue-router and Vue 3. I have a view where I'd like to take the router url and use it to call a method to access an API. This method returns a promise I can use to populate my page. When calling my method with 'route.params.id', it says that the parameter is undefined. When I do console.log(route.params.id), it displays correctly in console. I've tried using a computed property instead, but I had the same issue.

Setup code:

```
import { ref } from "vue";
import MovieApiService from "../api/MovieApiService";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";

export default {
  setup() {
    const movie = ref([]);
    const route = useRoute();

    MovieApiService.getMovie(route.params.id).then((response) => {
      movie.value = response.data.results;
    });

    return {
      movie,
    };
  },
  method: {},
};
```

Method being called:

```
static getMovie(body: GetMovieByTmdbId) {
    return axios.get(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${body.id}?api_key=${apiKey}`
    );
  }
```

Here's what I tried to compute the property instead, with the same result.

```
setup() {
    const route = useRoute();
    const id = computed(()=>{return route.params.id})

    const movie = ref([]);

    getMovie(id).then((response) => {
      movie.value = response.data.results;
      console.log(movie.value);
    });
```

How should I ensure this value is available when I call my method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving `route.params.id` as a variable to `getMovie(body)`.

You are then using `body.id` in your URL. This would equal `route.params.id.id` which is not defined.

Use `body` in your URL, or change the parameter to `id` so is makes more sense.

Like this:

```js
...
const route = useRoute();
MovieApiService.getMovie(route.params.id).then((response) => {
  movie.value = response.data.results;
});
...
```

```js
const getMovie = (id) => {
  return axios.get(
    `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=${apiKey}`
  );
}
```